# The hiring manager forgot to call me three times now; how to proceed?

Tags: job-search, hiring-process, unprofessional-behavior, consulting

This is for consultant role at a major hospital. I got an email from the recruiter and they forwarded me to the hiring manager. I was excited as it's a great job regarding pay, location, company and line of work.

I had my first call set up - they forgot.

I emailed them after 20 minutes and they called me back, it was 40 minutes later by then. They invited me to an personal interview.

I got another email with an invite to talk one the phone before the actual interview. We set up an appointment.

They never actually called. Not even an apology.

I had my in person interview talked to a lot of different people and it felt positive. Two weeks later, the hiring manager asks me if I am still available and if we can talk on the phone. I say yes.
They never call me - yet again!!

I am just soo frustrated with this. I have been prepared for each of the interviews and even took an uber twice instead of the bus to be faster at home to be on time. It's so rude!!

I keep my calm and we set up another time this morning and I am not sure anymore if I was just stood up again. 
The email read: "Can we talk at 3pm or 1 pm tomorrow?"
I said 3pm assuming its today but I once again have not received a call.

I want the job but I am beyond frustrated. If I would take the job I also would be working together with this hiring manager and if they were my supervisor I don't know how I would deal with this on a regular basis.

How would you react to this behavior? What would you do? Should I call them out?

Thank you!!!

Comment: As a consultant, would you risk to work for such a customer? What if the finance dept has the same attitude when invoice time comes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I want the job but I am beyond frustrated. If I would take the job I also would be working together with this hiring manager and if they were my supervisor I don't know how I would deal with this on a regular basis.
>
> How would you react to this behavior? What would you do?

I'm sorry you experienced this; surely it can be frustrating.

I must say that I agree with you in the fact that *this reflects poorly on the hiring manager and the company's practices and punctuality*. To me, this is a red flag and would strongly consider if working there is worth it if they eventually reached out (or I will be sure to ask during interviews so I can get an idea if this is the norm).

I suggest you do two things:

1. Continue pursuing this opportunity in case they reach out. Best case they were in a bad streak, and you feel comfortable after the interview and are able to take this job you want.
2. I strongly suggest you **keep your options open and pursue alternate jobs in the meanwhile**. Don't put all your eggs in one basked. Consider searching and applying to other job openings and opportunities you see so you don't waste your time in this company in case this doesn't work out.

Comment: As an addition to #1, you could ask for their number and offer to call them instead so you aren't relying on them to remember the meeting. And if you haven't been already, set up a meeting over GCalendar/iCal/Outlook/etc.

Comment: good suggestions @DavidK

Answer (score 7):

If that is how they treat interviewees, then how they treat their staff must be fantastic (not)...

This is a red flag to find something else... unless they impress you with their explanation at the eventual interview, if of course, it ever happens...

So, if you work in teams on shifts and there are shift changes - how will you get notification of changes? You might come in for the PM shift - “where were you, we expected you this morning” and you check your email to find an email sent 10 minutes after the start of shift...

Answer (score 5):

> How would you react to this behavior? What would you do? Should I call them out?

They don't value your time. The last time a hiring manager did that to me, they missed 3 interview time slots. Apologized each time. Finally when I did a ~30 minute interview and was told that a former co-worker of mine who works at the same company had given me a great reference. After I get off the call I notice a notification from Indeed.com that was emailed to me just 2 minutes into the call telling me that the hiring manager had rejected me as a candidate. Last time I give a guy like that the chance to waste my time.

No I wouldn't bother calling them out. Not going to help you.

Comment: *＋1*, walk away. The company does not respect your time and shows contempt for its candidates. I had SpaceX do the same to me. The recruiter kept setting up and missing calls, and responding late to emails. After the third time I walked away and blacklisted the recruiter's email address.

Answer (score 3):

Goldfinger's Rule: "Once is happenstance.  Twice is coincidence.  Three times is enemy action."  (according to Ian Fleming)

Either the hiring manager is deliberately ignoring you, or he is INCREDIBLY disorganized.  In either case, you don't want to work for him.

Move on.